Is there a way to duplicate a RTK slice into an array every time a user clicks the button?
Let's say i developed component A which is quite complex with slice A. Then i received a requirement which i need to make component A be replicable each time a button is clicked and have their own slice A. Is there a way for me to duplicate that slice into an array every time a user clicks the button?
As of now i am in the process of developing component B with a slice that holds an array of component B state. My problem here now is, every time i re-render (e.g. typing in an input) it takes almost 100ms per 1 letter as opposed to component A which took 20ms per 1 letter. Besides implementing useRef and debouncing, is there any other approach that i can do?

I solved my problem for component B. Apparently i made a very big blunder and a novice mistake. When i ported my component A logic to component B, instead of something like
// Good
const data = useSelector((state) => state.componentB.array.find((item) => item.id === currentId).data) 
const fields = useSelector((state) => state.componentB.array.find((item) => item.id === currentId).fields)


I did this
// Bad
const currentComponent = useSelector((state) => state.componentB.array.find((item) => item.id === currentId))
const data = currentComponent.data
const fields = currentComponent.fields


I had to give myself some hour of rest to suddenly realize i forgot about the basics. Now its re-rendering at 20ms instead of 100ms since it is not fetching the whole object every single keystroke.
As for the first problem, i am not sure if it is even possible to somehow add in a new duplicated slice in an array of some sort so that i don't have to redevelop the component.

Use React.memo to wrap your component and tell React to only re-render when its props change.
Edit: If your focus is on performance, then you should get familiar with some good practices of React like react-virtualized, react-window, immutable-data-structures, selective-state-updating
